# Vue.JS data in HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm working with Vue.JS right now and a status bar and I was wondering how to put data from vue in an html attribute.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
        <span class="sr-only">${this.score}% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
        <span class="sr-only">${this.score}% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the v-bind: doesn't work.

Comment: try aria-valuenow="{{ score }} and if you changed the default brackets it will be like aria-valuenow="${score}%"

Comment: `aria-valuenow="{{ score }}"` will not work. Interpolation in attributes are now deprecated, instead use `v-bind` like `v-bind:aria-valuenow="score"` or `:aria-valuenow="score"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    score: 20
  }
});
```

```css
[aria-valuenow="20"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" v-bind:aria-valuenow="score" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
    <span class="sr-only">${{this.score}}% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it via your snippet and it worked. Thanks dude!

Comment: Also worked for me. Got stuck with binding my value within curly brackets. Removed them and its good now.